# Is it possible to find out a value that is the most different with pure Sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

Lets say I have a list of url's and I want to find out the domain that is the that appears the fewest times. Here is an example of the database:

```
3598 ('www.emp.de/blog/tag/fear-factory/')
3599 ('www.emp.de/blog/tag/white-russian/')
3600 ('www.emp.de/blog/musik/die-emp-plattenkiste-zum-07-august-2015/')
3601 ('www.emp.de/Warenkorb/car_/')
3602 ('www.emp.de/ter_dataprotection/')
3603 ('hilfe.monster.de/my20/faq.aspx#help_1_211589')
3604 ('jobs.monster.de/l-nordrhein-westfalen.aspx')
3605 ('karriere-beratung.monster.de')
3606 ('karriere-beratung.monster.de')
```

In this case it should return jobs.monster.de or hilfe.monster.de. I only want one return value. Is that possible with pure Sqlite3?

It should be some kind of counting of the main url before the ".de"

At this moment I do it this way:

```
con.execute("select url, date from urls_to_visit ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: Do all the domains end in `.de`?

Comment: yes. i only have .de domains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query which should handle this correctly:

```sql
SELECT substr(url, 1, instr(url, '.de')-1)
FROM urls_to_visit
WHERE url LIKE '%.de%'
-- insurance, can leave out if you're sure the whole table matches
GROUP BY substr(url, 1, instr(url, '.de')-1)
ORDER BY count(*) ASC, RANDOM()
LIMIT 1;
```

Group on the thing we want to sort by, then order by `count(*)`.  This expression extracts the part of the URL before the `.de/`:

```
substr(url, 1, instr(url, '.de')-1)
```

The `RANDOM()` ensures that ties are broken randomly instead of by following the table's natural ordering.*  It *only* comes into play if there is a tie, as described in [the SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby).

---

* Technically, the rows would not appear in natural order, but in *arbitrary* order.  That means whatever order is most convenient for the query planner.  Database systems often use [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) or a variant, which is a stable sort, so ties will be consistently broken in the order the rows were fed into the sorting algorithm.  Unless the query can benefit significantly from index lookups, which this one almost certainly can't, the most likely query plan is a full table scan, so the sort will typically end up following natural order.  **But you can't rely on any of this,** since the standard does not formally require it.

Comment: hey thanks that works. only problem is when I expand the limit I see the values are in alphabetic order. is there a way to avoid this? in other words. domains that start with a b c are highly prefered over x y z

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine: I imagine ties are being broken by natural order (the order the rows appear in the table).  I would suppose you are clustering on the URL, since that would produce this kind of ordering, or maybe it's just an artifact of SQLite.  You could add `, RANDOM()` after the `count(*)` if you need ties to be broken in random order.

Comment: Could you maybe show me the whole example of what you mean with random? because if I think about random then it destroies the effect of fewness again.